# React Native: should modules be imported in MainActivity.java or MainApplication.java

Tags: android, reactjs, xcode, react-native, module

I'm adding [this module](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-text-input-mask) to my React Native project and in the documentation it says to import it in `MainActivity.java`. However, when I look back at project where I've used it before, I imported it (and all other modules) in `MainApplication.java`. Which should I import them in? I'm using React Native 0.60.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right you need to use MainApplication not MainActivity i guess they misstyped.